# Rails Polymorphic Association with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations, polymorphic-associations

This is the case: I have 4 models which are "owner", "user", "location" and "landlord". All of these models share email addresses and phones. So I'm thinking to use Polymorphic Association and I made a research but I just see cases for 3 models. In my case as you can see I will have more than 3 models.

So, do you think is a good idea to implement this kind of logic where I want to use a model like the "repository" for all emails and phones numbers?

There is a limit or something in order to use that kind of association?. I'm thinking in some models like:

```
email
emailable
user
owner
landlord
location
```

Each model will have their necessary fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit. A polymorphic association is an open interface that any other model can plug into. In your example, maybe you have a `Contact` model, which `belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true`. The `contacts` table will need two indexed columns: `contactable_id:integer`, and `contactable_type:string`. Any other model can be `contactable`, as long as it `has_one :contact, as: :contactable`.

As far as if it's a good idea, I'd say if you think you will need to work with `contacts` as a separate entity from the `contactable` models, then this is a good solution. However, if you won't need to deal directly with `contacts` then it might be overcomplicating when you could just add `email` and `phone` fields to these models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on my description where I will have around 7 models with emails/phones I think is like a good way to define a single model for that.

But I open to other ideas, because I don't want to overcomplicating. In your professional opinion what do you suggest @m. simo borg ?.

Thanks again